# A new entity was found through the relationship?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a handle code

```
if ($this->request->isMethod('POST') && $valid) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $formData = $form->getData();
            $staffValue = $formData['staff'];
            $campaignDetailFilter = $modelCampaignDetail->getRepository()->countDataByCampaignDetailId($formData['campaignDetail']);
            $total         = count($campaignDetailFilter);
            $totalStaff = count($formData['staff']);

            foreach ($campaignDetailFilter as $valDetailId) {
                $detailDataEntity = $modelDetailData->getEntity($valDetailId['id']);
                $batchSize = $total / $totalStaff;
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($staffValue as $staffVal) {
                    $detailDataEntity->setStaff($staffVal);
                    $em->persist($detailDataEntity);
                    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
                        $em->flush();
                        $em->clear();
                    }
                    ++$i;
                }
                $em->flush();
                $em->clear();
            }
        }
```

But when I give $i = 0 it gets an error: **A new entity was found through the relationship...that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove $em->clear().

```
if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
     $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank bro. I have one more problem. Please help me. In variable : "$staffVal" 
For example I have two employees (id: 2, id :3). I have ten row want equally divided for those two employees. But when I am : $detailDataEntity->setStaff($staffVal) 
then it just set (id : 3).I did it wrong. Help me please !

Comment: @n2k you can try: $employee = $em->getRepository(Employees::class)->find($staffVal); $detailDataEntity->setStaff($employee);